# Rearrange list the same way as another one

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I bumped into a page where there were a lot of categories and next to each one the number of items in each category, wrapped in parenthesis. Something really common. It looked like this:

```
Category 1 (2496)
Category 2 (34534)
Category 3 (1039)
Category 4 (9)
...
```

So I was curious and I wanted to see which categories had more items and such, and since all categories were all together in the page I could just select them all and copy them in a text file, making things really easy.

I made a little program that reads all the numbers, store them in a list and sort them. In order to know what category the number it belonged to I would just `Ctrl + F` the number in the browser.

But I thought it would be nice to have the name of the category next to the number in my text file, and I managed to parse them in another file. However, they are not ordered, obviously.

This is what I could do so far:

```
bool is_number(const string& s) {
    return !s.empty() && find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !isdigit(c); }) == s.end();
}

int main() {
    ifstream file;
    ofstream file_os, file_t_os;

    string word, text; // word is the item count and text the category name
    list<int> words_list; // list of item counts
    list<string> text_list; // list of category names

    file.open("a.txt");
    file_os.open("a_os.txt");
    file_t_os.open("a_t_os.txt");

    while (file >> word) {
        if (word.front() == '(' && word.back() == ')') { // check if it's being read something wrapped in parenthesis
            string old_word = word;
            word.erase(word.begin());
            word.erase(word.end()-1);
            if (is_number(word)) { // check if it's a number (item count)
                words_list.push_back(atoi(word.c_str()));
                text.pop_back(); // get rid of an extra space in the category name
                text_list.push_back(text);
                text.clear();
            } else { // it's part of the category name
                text.append(old_word);
                text.append(" ");
            }
        } else {
            text.append(word);
            text.append(" ");
        }
    }

    words_list.sort();

    for (list<string>::iterator it = text_list.begin(); it != text_list.end(); ++it) {
        file_t_os << *it << endl;
    }

    for (list<int>::iterator it = words_list.begin(); it != words_list.end(); ++it) {
        file_os << fixed << *it << endl;
    }

    cout << text_list.size() << endl << words_list.size() << endl; // I'm getting the same count
}
```

Now I forget about having the name next to the number, because something more interesting occured to me. I thought it would be interesting to find a way to rearrange the `string`s in the `text_list` which contain the names of the categories in the exact same way the list with the item count was sorted.

Let me explain with an example, lets say we have the following categories:

```
A (5)
B (3)
C (10)
D (6)
```

The way I'm doing it I will have a `list<int>` containing this: `{10, 6, 5, 3}` and a `list<string>` containing this: `{A, B, C, D}`.

What I'm saying is I want to find a way I can keep track of the way the elements were rearranged in the first list and apply that very pattern to the second list. What would be the rearrange pattern? It would be: *the first item (5) goes to the third position, the second one (3) to the fourth one, the third one (10) to the first one, and so on...*. Then this pattern should be applied to the other list, so that it would end up like this: `{C, D, A, B}`.

[image]

The thing would be to keep track of the **Pattern** and apply it to the list below.

Is there any way I can do this? Any particular function that could help me? Any way to track all the swaps and switches the `sort` algorithm does so it can be applied to a different list with **the same size**? What about a different sorting algorithm?

I know this might be highly inefficient and a bad idea, but it seemed like a little challenge.

I also know I could just pair both `string` and `int`, category and item count, in some sort of container like `pair` or `map` or make a container class of my own and sort the items based on the item count (I guess `map` would be the best choice, what do you think?), but this is not what I am asking.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I have _no_ idea what you're talking about...

Comment: I updated my question with an example, maybe it helps. It's not that easy to explain what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to create a list that contains both sets of information you want to sort and feed in a custom sorting function.

For instance:

```
struct Record {
  string name;
  int count;
};

list<Record> myList;

sort(myList, [](Record a, Record b){
    return a.count < b.count;
  });
```

In the general case, it's always better to manage one list of a complex datatype, than to try to separately manage two or more lists of simple datatypes, especially when they're mutable.

Comment: Then to answer your question, the answer is no.  std::sort does not expose this information.  And moreover, attempting to do this would almost certainly be the wrong approach.

Comment: However, if you were so inclined, of course, you could implement your own sort function to do this.

Comment: my own function to do what?

Comment: Your own sort function to generate a sorted list and a list of ints that maps the source index to the destination index.  Then another custom function to apply it.  I still think that you should never ever do this in real code, of course.  And there's no utility in the standard library to do it.  But it's not impossible.

Comment: I am aware I should never do this and it's a terrible idea. The question is just out of curiosity; more the challenge of thinking of ways of keeping track of the sorting pattern than the efficiency of the sorting itself. I just wanted to hear ideas on how to create this tracking functions, like your idea ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60042/discussion-between-omnipotententity-and-dabadaba).

Comment: could you delete/edit your answer? It doesn't answer what I'm asking. You could update it with what you told me in chat.

Comment: While it's not the answer to the question you were asking, it is the most useful answer to this kind of question in the general case and it's the more valuable answer to have listed on this page imo, for future visitors to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Some more improve way:

First some notes:

- It's recommended to storage category name and items together, for clarity, easy of read code, etc...
- It's better use `std::vector` instead of `std::list` (see [Bjarne Stroustrup opinion](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/06/stroustrup-lists))
- The code load the file with the format specified in your question, storage in the vector the info pair.
- Use `std::sort` function to sort only by items number (the categories with the same items would be in any order, if you would like to sort for category name the categories with the same items change the lambda body to `return std::tie(left.items, left.name) > std::tie(right.items, right.name);`.
- Added a version with info split, in one collection items and index (to correlate items with name) info, and in the other names info.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

bool is_number(const std::string& s) {
    return !s.empty() &&
           find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) { return !isdigit(c); }) ==
               s.end();
}

struct category_info {
    std::string name;
    int items;
};

struct category_items_info {
    int items;
    size_t index;
};

int main() {
    std::ifstream file("H:\\save.txt");

    std::vector<category_info> categories;
    std::vector<category_items_info> categories_items;
    std::vector<std::string> categories_names;

    std::string word;
    std::string text;
    while (file >> word) {
        if (word.front() == '(' && word.back() == ')') {
            std::string inner_word = word.substr(1, word.size() - 2);
            if (is_number(inner_word)) {
                std::string name = text.substr(0, text.size() - 1);
                int items = atoi(inner_word.c_str());

                categories.push_back(category_info{name, items});
                categories_names.push_back(name);
                categories_items.push_back(
                    category_items_info{items, categories_items.size()});

                text.clear();
            } else { // it's part of the category name
                text.append(word);
                text.append(" ");
            }
        } else {
            text.append(word);
            text.append(" ");
        }
    }

    std::sort(categories.begin(), categories.end(),
              [](const category_info& left, const category_info& right) {
        return left.items > right.items;
    });

    std::sort(
        categories_items.begin(), categories_items.end(),
        [](const category_items_info& left, const category_items_info& right) {
            return left.items > right.items;
        });

    std::cout << "Using the same storage." << std::endl;
    for (auto c : categories) {
        std::cout << c.name << " (" << c.items << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Using separated storage." << std::endl;
    for (auto c : categories_items) {
        std::cout << categories_names[c.index] << " (" << c.items << ")"
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output obtained:

```
Using the same storage.
Category 2 (34534)
Category 1 (2496)
Category 3 (1039)
Category 4 (9)

Using separated storage.
Category 2 (34534)
Category 1 (2496)
Category 3 (1039)
Category 4 (9)
```

Comment: thanks but I wasn't asking on how to arrange a pair of `{name, count}` based on the `count` value, as I stated in my last paragraph. I am asking of different ways of keeping track of the pattern applied to sort the **item count list** and apply this very pattern to the other list, the one with the **category names**

Comment: updated with a solution that might satisfied you, it's not maintaining track of the pattern, simply correlating `items -> name` and using this info for later print the result OK. It's almost the same as before, but the names are storage separately.

Answer (score 0):

Lists do not support random access iterators, so this is going to be a problem, since a list can't be permuted based on a vector (or array) of indices without doing a lot of list traversal back and forth to emulate random access iteration. NetVipeC's solution was to use vectors instead of lists to get around this problem. If using vectors, then you could generate a vector (or array) of indices to the vector to be sorted, then sort the vector indices using a custom compare operator. You could then copy the vectors according to the vector of sorted indices. It's also possible to reorder a vector in place according to the indices, but that algorithm also sorts the vector of indices, so you're stuck making a copy of the sorted indices (to sort the second vector), or copying each vector in sorted index order.

If you really want to use lists, you could implement your own std::list::sort, that would perform the same operations on both lists. The Microsoft version of std::list::sort uses an array of lists where the number of nodes in array[i] = 2^i, and it merges nodes one at a time into the array, then when all nodes are processed, it merges the lists in the array to produce a sorted list. You'd need two arrays, one for each list to be sorted. I can post example C code for this type of list sort if you want.

Comment: Sure some little sample can always help